# How do I call special function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, post

I'm trying to get a string by post method in jQuery by calling a method.
Here is my code:

```
 $("#btn_Submit").submit(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "frm_GetTable.aspx/GetComment",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
             $("#Comment").empty().html(data);                     
         }
     });
```

and this is my function :

```
protected String GetComment ()
    {
        String Comment="";


        Comment=(" <table>");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt_Comment)
        {
            Comment +=("<tr ><td>  </td><td rowspan='2'> " + dr["Com"].ToString() + " </td></tr>");
            Comment += ("<tr><td >" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");

        }
        Comment += ("</table>");
        return Comment;
    }
```

When I submit it shows `Error :The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted`.
Please help, I cant understand where the problem is.

Comment: use `static` declaration

Comment: `data: "{}"` looks wrong. I know it's supposed to be a JSON representation of a raw js plain object but surely jQuery will stringify whatever is specified here anyway. `data: {}` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should make the function [`public static`](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)
2. Add `[WebMethod]` attribute to the function

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static string GetComment()
   {
       String Comment = "";
       Comment = (" <table>");
       foreach (DataRow dr in dt_Comment)
       {
           Comment += ("<tr ><td>  </td><td rowspan='2'> " + dr["Com"].ToString() + " </td></tr>");
           Comment += ("<tr><td >" + dr["Date"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
       }
       Comment += ("</table>");
       return Comment;
   }
   ```

Comment: when I add [WebMethod] at the first of my function asp.net couldn't recognize it.how can I solve it?